# Extract element from a list without repetition efficiently

Tags: python, list, networkx

I need to extract an exact number (extracted from a cumulative distribution) of value from a list without repetition (and also checking another constraint from a networkx DiGraph).

My list has more than 100000 elements (certain nodes from the networkx DiGraph)

My code looks like this:

```
def extractRandomSubset(alist,number,G #the graph):
    res={}
    count=0
    while count<number:
        el=random.choice(alist) #number extraction
        if el not in res.values() and G.nodes[el]["weight"]!=0: #my two constraints
            res[count]=el
            count+=1                    
    return res
```

My code takes from 0.001 s to 0.5 s and I need to do it 100000 times so it will take a long time. Is there a way to improve it to run faster?

EDIT: the type I used can all be changed (for example alist can be also some other data type), the one I put are the ones that was working well with a part of the data (a smaller sample). The only thing is that I need the result to be ordered (so set is not a good option)

Comment: It is hard to provide feedback without more context. Can you provide code to produce  `list` (you may want to rename this variable), `number` and `G`?

Comment: I used list just to give a generic name, all the names I have are different. G is a nx.DiGraph already existing, it has approximately 200000 nodes some positive and some negative (50%-50% approx.), alist are the positive nodes in the graph saved in a list. Number is just an extraction from a cumulative distribution (it could be every natural number, but in the given ditribution there are a lot more 0,1,2 than high number, the maximum in the graph I am trying is 81)

Comment: the slow step is `if el not in res.values()` - it has to do a complete search through a growing list each time.  You need a way to store the values in a data type that allows for a quick check (say, a set).  It's also not clear to me why `res` is a dict and not a list.

Comment: @Joel it was a dict because it seemed to me that it was faster than using a list that I used starting the creation(I checked it practically with `time.time()` and it is definetely faster). I will try with sets, there are other data type where the search is quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to shuffle the whole list and take the top `count` values that fit your second condition:

```
def extractRandomSubset(_list,number,G):
    from random import shuffle
    shuffle(_list) # now items in _list are shuffled randomly
    ret = []
    for el in _list:
        if len(ret) >= number:
            return ret
        if G.nodes[el]["weight"]!=0:
            ret.append(el)
    # handle the case where you don't have enough nodes with nonzero weights in G
    raise ValueError('Not enough nodes with nonzero weight!')
```

---

Another version of the same idea first filters out all values that don't have a positive weight and then shuffles:

```
def extractRandomSubset(_list,number,G):
    from random import shuffle
    valid_items = [el for el in _list if G.nodes[el]["weight"]!=0]
    shuffle(valid_items)
    if len(valid_items) < number:
        raise ValueError('Not enough nodes with nonzero weight!')
    return valid_items[:number]
```

Personally, I prefer this option because:

1. the syntax is much cleaner and the intent clearly expressed in code
2. you avoid multiple allocations by not appending one item at a time to the list (this may be a big source of slowdown)

Whichever is fastest depends entirely on the number of elements in `_list`, `G` and the value of `number` (I expect for big lists and low `number` values, the frst option may be faster).

---

The second version of the code can also be implemented using `random.sample()` instead of shuffle + take the head (it's equivalent but it may have different performance, depending on the exact parameter values):

```
def extractRandomSubset(_list,number,G):
    from random import shuffle, sample
    valid_items = [el for el in _list if G.nodes[el]["weight"]!=0]
    return sample(valid_items, number)
```

---

PS: it's a bad idea to call a variable `list` (hence why I use `_list` instead), or any other name that masks python keyworkds/types.

Comment: Yes I know list is not a good name to use it was only to make clear of what it was, I edited it anyway

Comment: Also it seems to me as impossible that  `len(valid_items) < number` so the value error is not a problem in my experience with data

Comment: @DuccioBorchi With the knowledge of the problem you have, it's unlikely. In the context of the question (and as a general engineering prectice), however, the exceptional case may happen and it's good to explicitly raise the excepion instead of relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes you are right I did not think about the general context

Comment: I tried this solution and it is quite good but not so faster (0.008 s faster in mean for 100000 simulation). I was looking for something better, maybe by changing some data type I can make it a little bit better?

Comment: @DuccioBorchi I added a version that uses python's `random.sample` directly. I don't know if this is any faster, since most of the time is spent checking that the items are in G anyhow, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Yes I've seen it, thanks. I think that is the faster it can go, maybe I'm asking too much for what I need to do